# How to read data from password protected excel file with informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

**Pl help** me to read data from a password protected excel file with informatica

Basically i need to convert excel to csv and read with informatica

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Never done that, but I would do as follows.

Excel is accessible using ODBC. So define a ODBC data source in the server
(you would probably have to define a NAME in excel to delimitate the area you want imported).

Using (in Designer).  Source->Import from database 
you can then create the Source and specify the password.